# Cannot resolve keyword 'model' into field. Piston with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, backbone.js, django-piston

I am trying to send a Backbone.js model as a POST to Piston and am getting an error:

Piston/0.2.2 (Django 1.3) crash report:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston/handler.py",
    line 81, in create inst = self.model.objects.get(**attrs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py",
    line 132, in get return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
    line 341, in get clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
    line 550, in filter return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
    line 568, in _filter_or_exclude clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
    line 1172, in add_q can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
    line 1060, in add_filter negate=negate, process_extras=process_extras)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py",
    line 1238, in setup_joins "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(names)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'model' into field.
    Choices are: calendar, date, id, name, priority
```

The code:

```
$(function() {
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
$('form').submit(function() {

    formdict = jsonform($("form#add_task :input"));


   var new_task = new Task({
    calendar: formdict.calendar,
    date: formdict.date,
    name: formdict.name,
    priority: formdict.priority});
    console.log("new _task: " + new_task);
     new_task.save();


    return false;
});

});

});
```

Response and Request Information:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/api/task/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:156
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
model:{"date":"2012-03-10T01:12:43.876Z","name":"New event","priority":0,"id":1,"calendar":"null"}
```

Response Headersview source

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 10 Mar 2012 01:12:44 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.2+
Vary:Authorization
```

How do I get Piston to accept the model?

Comment: What is the request sent to the server? This is obviously server-side error, could you share relevant part with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well clearly you send

```
{model:{"date":"2012-03-10T01:12:43.876Z","name":"New event","priority":0,"id":1,"calendar":"null"}}
```

whereas your server side expects:

{"date":"2012-03-10T01:12:43.876Z","name":"New event","priority":0,"id":1,"calendar":"null"}

So either you change Backbone's `sync()` to not include `model` in JSON or your server side.
I don't use Django but simply looking at https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#!working-with-models gives me the impression that it's as simple as:

```
class ModelHandler(BaseHandler):
   fields = (('model', ('id', 'name', 'date', 'priority', 'calendar'),))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error code says:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'model' into field.
   Choices are: calendar, date, id, name, priority
```

Apparently you are sending wrong POST data. Open the debug console and check what is being posted by the save() function and see if that match what  Piston expects. You can see the POST url and parameters in the network tab of firebug/chrome console.

Comment: It is posting a model:

model:{"date":"2012-03-10T01:12:43.876Z","name":"New event","priority":0,"id":1,"calendar":"null"}

Comment: your server is getting the JSON as {model:{calendar:'', priority:'', etc... }} but seems to expect only as {calendar:'', priority:'', etc..}. Change your Piston code to read model.calendar instead of calendar only

Comment: I'm aware. I don't know how to get rid of the model. I thought posting with backbone models to piston was possible.

Comment: is it possible to change Piston code to read model.date instead?

Comment: @user784756: Show us the code you tried (the one saying _model is undefined_).

Comment: I can't help you with Piston/Django. But I recommend to solve the issue server-side and don't mess too much with the way Backbone posts data. Sorry I can't be more helpful.